# Problemas con load_file en mysql

Tags: mysql

Hola gente les comento,

tengo una db en mysql con la siguiente tabla (entre otras):

```
create table documentos(
   id int primary key not null auto_increment,
   archivo blob not null,
   codigo varchar(55) not null,
   nombre varchar(55) not null,
   tipo_doc varchar(55) not null,
   subproceso varchar(55) not null,
   proceso varchar(55) not null,
   depto_unidad varchar(55) not null,
   division varchar(55) not null,
   fecha_aprobacion date not null,
  fecha_modificacion date not null
);
```

Es primera vez que trabajo con una columna BLOB y necesito cargar archivos a la db, para ello estoy haciendo un insert tal que:

```
insert into documentos values
(null, load_file('C:\allmyCode\src\sql\Files\doc1.txt'), 'DOC1', 'Documento N1', 'Tpdc1', 'Sbprcs1', 'Prcs1', 'Dptundd1', 'Dvsn1', '2020-11-23', '2020-11-23');
```

pero me arroja un Error Code: 1048. Column 'archivo' cannot be null.

El único dato null que hago es a la columna con el auto_increment, que me funciona bien en las demás tabla y al probar a quitarlo de esta no soluciona el problema.

Para asegurarme he probado con todos los tipos de barras tanto '/', '\', '//' y '\\'.

Acabo de leer un poco buscando soluciones y he ejecutado SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv"; para ver el directorio predeterminado y he probado en colocar los documentos ahí y hacer el insert:

```
insert into documentos values
(null, load_file('\doc1.txt'), 'DOC1', 'Documento N1', 'Tpdc1', 'Sbprcs1', 'Prcs1', 'Dptundd1', 'Dvsn1', '2020-11-23', '2020-11-23');
```

Esta vez lo probé sin barras y con todos los tipos de barras nuevamente. Me sigue dando el mismo error.

A su vez leí que hay que hay que verificar los privilegios, con lo que usé un GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'; y luego FLUSH PRIVILEGES; no me arrojó error pero no estoy seguro de si esta sea la forma ni la sintaxis correcta (me aseguré de hacer esto antes de hacer las pruebas con load_file('doc1.txt') y sus variantes barrísticas).

Mencionar por último que el archivo es de prueba, es un txt vacío (probé también con escribirle dos líneas de texto), por lo que no debería ser problema el tamaño del archivo.

Utilizo windows 10 y mysqlserver / workbench 8.0. Lo que intento hacer con crear una tabla para cargar documentos es mostrar sus datos y posiblemente descargar el archivo desde una página html desarrollada con node.js usando extensiones .ejs; cualquier consejo respecto a esto será de mucha ayuda.

¡Gracias por sus respuestas!